# List comprehension with list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Please see this JSON structure:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "blabla1",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "blabla2",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "blabla3",
    "value": "3"
  }
]
```

And I have a simple class:

```
@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str = field(init=True)
    value: str = field(init=True)
    is_valid: bool = field(init=False, default=True)
```

And I want to read this file and create a list of this data class.

This is what I have tried:

```
v = ...
```

This `v` contains a list of dictionaries (3 according my example here)

```
data = [[(Data(name=k, value=v, is_valid=True)) for k, v in v.items()] for d in v]
```

The results here is a list of 7 Data `types` but for each item in this list I have another list of 2 items with Data `type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ads the JSON file and returns a list of Data objects. Each object is created by passing the name and value fields from the corresponding dictionary in the JSON file. The is_valid field is set to True by default:

```
import json

@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str
    value: str
    is_valid: bool = True

def read_json_file(file_path: str) -> List[Data]:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return [Data(d['name'], d['value']) for d in data]
```

Answer (score 2):

@Abdulmajeed's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75613324/1862861) is the best option, but just as an alternative, you could use the [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function, e.g.,

```py
from ast import literal_eval

@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str
    value: str
    is_valid: bool = True

def read_json_file(file_path: str) -> List[Data]:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        data = literal_eval(f.read())
    return [Data(d['name'], d['value']) for d in data]
```